# Execute query against MSSQL database using Microsoft PHP Driver 3.2

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am working on a project to connect to a MSSQL database and execute queries against it and am definitely new in this.

So what I have done so far is to setup WAMP, add Microsoft PHP driver for PHP 5.5 in php.ini and created a successful connection to my database with this code:

```
    <?php
    $server = 'servername,1433';
    $database = 'database_name';
    $user = 'username';
    $password = 'pass';

    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server;Database=$database", 
              "$user", "$password", 
              array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
             );
    ?>
```

I am using SQL Server 2014. Just to mention this. So now I trying to display some info from a table in my database with this:

```
<?php
require_once('sqlcon.php');

function GetRow($stmt)
{
return sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.operations";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = GetRow($stmt) ) {
      echo ("<tr>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['id'] . "</tr>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['OperType'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['Acct'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['GoodID'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['PartnerID'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['ObjectID'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['OperatorID'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['Qtty'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['Sign'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['PriceIn'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['PriceOut'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['VatIn'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['VatOut'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['Discount'] . "</td>");
            echo ("<td>" . $row['Currency'] . "</td>");
            echo ("</tr>");
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```

But I am receiving this error in browser:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_query() in
>   C:\wamp\www\sql.php on line 11 Call Stack
>
> ## Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0005  139320  {main}( )   ..\sql.php:0

I have tried many times with different functions but with no luck. I do not know why sqlsrv_query() function is not being recognized.

I know I am missing something but do not know what. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following adjustment using the full SQL Server PDO API.

Your code declares a PDO during connection but you don't use that object `$conn->query()` but use `$conn` as an argument in the `sqlsrv_query()` function. Hence, you conflate the two APIs: [SQLSRV and PDO](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/04/20/comparing-the-sqlsrv-and-pdo-apis.aspx). In order to use [sqlsrv_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php), you need to connect using sqlsrv_connect(). Otherwise, use the `query` or `prepare` and `execute` statements.

```
<?php

$server = 'servername,1433';
$database = 'database_name';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'pass';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server;Database=$database", 
                     $user, $password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.operations";    
    $STH = $conn->query($sql);

    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
        echo ("<tr>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['id'] . "</tr>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['OperType'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['Acct'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['GoodID'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['PartnerID'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['ObjectID'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['OperatorID'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['Qtty'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['Sign'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['PriceIn'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['PriceOut'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['VatIn'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['VatOut'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['Discount'] . "</td>");
        echo ("<td>" . $row['Currency'] . "</td>");
        echo ("</tr>");
}

# close the connection
$conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Parfait . My misunderstanding. Now everything is fine with the SQLSRV API and now I am using sqlsrv_connect() with the right dll's for PHP from Microsoft. Thank you once again.